# Why does svg not get requested with app load

Tags: svg, next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I've got a live site https://courageous-kulfi-58c13b.netlify.app/. Whenever a checkbox is clicked, it should turn green with a tick svg on it. However, on the first app load, clicking a checkbox will show a noticeable delay between the background turning green and the tick svg actually showing. NextJS only requests for the svg once I click on the checkbox. The svg is used in my css as a background image in a `::before` pseudo element. How can I make next request for the svg in initial render so there isn't this delay?

```js
const Checkbox = (props: Props) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setChecked((prevChecked) => !prevChecked);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onClick={handleClick}
        className={cn({
          "before:bg-tick": checked,
        })}
      ></input>
    </>
  );
};
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
   extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        tick: "url(/Tick.svg)",
      },
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inline the svg with something like the following. Then there will be no delay in downloading the svg.

```css
.tick:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 342.357 342.357" style="enable-background:new 0 0 342.357 342.357" xml:space="preserve"><path d="M290.04 33.286 118.861 204.427l-66.541-66.52L0 190.226l118.862 118.845L342.357 85.606z"/></svg>');
}
```

Note I have run the svg through `svgo` to optimize it.

Example here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/TlRvKKs53I?file=css

**Preload image**

The other option would be to preload the image in the html head.

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="/Tick.svg">
```

The old school hacky way was to include an image tag on the page somewhere, but use css to make it not visible, but the browser would still load it.

Comment: This is a nice workaround tho nextjs does suggest placing static content in the public folder which you cant do if you inline svgs, I was looking more so for a nextjs configuration solution

Comment: The svg asset is 245 bytes so I would find it easier to use the first option and as a pure css solution. But I have added a second option for how to preload an image with html. Both are applicable for Next.js, or any stack for that matter.